# if then for non scalars and less equal comparison

Tags: matlab, if-statement

How would you implement:

```
if(m <= 0.1)
...
end
```

if m is not a scalar. I tried something along those lines:

```
array = ones(length(m), 1)  .* 0.1;
if(m <= array)
...
end
```

without success.

Comment: What is m ? And what it means m<=0.1 if m is not a scalar?

Comment: related question: [how to threshold/filter a vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132231/how-to-threshold-filter-a-vector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely want

```
if all(m <= 0.1)
```

but maybe

```
if any(m <= 0.1)
```

It's even one of the examples for the [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) function.

But in fact [the documentation for `if`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) suggests that

```
if (m <= 0.1)
```

should work just fine also.

Comment: +1: You could also use `mode` to check for the majority of values.

Comment: Note that `if (m <= 0.1)` is equivalent to `if all(m <= 0.1)`